# String compare and length

Tags: c, string, comparison, string-length

Hi I am trying to right a program but am having so much difficulty. The program is a challenge I made up myself. I want to read in 6 strings from the user. Then I want to create a function that will allow me to compare those strings to find which string is different in size. Then I want to pass this info to another function that will determine the string length of the string that is different. Finally print the value. Here is what I have done thus far (many many errors).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* diffFun(char* ,char*,char * ,char *,char * ,char *)
    {
    char *s1;
    char *s2;
    char *s3;
    char *s4;
    char *s5;
    char *s6;
    char *result;
    if (strcmp(s2,s3,s4,s5,s6)<strcmp(s1))
            result =  s1;
    else if (strcmp(s1,s3,s4,s5,s6)<strcmp(s2))
            result s2;
    return result;
    }

int main()
    {
    char *str1;
    char *str2;
    char *str3;
    char *str4;
    char *str5;
    char *str6;

    printf("Give me a string1:\n");
    str1 = readString(stdin);
    printf("Give me a string2:\n");
    str2 = readString(stdin);
    printf("Give me a string3:\n");
    str3 = readString(stdin);
    printf("Give me a string4:\n");
    str4 = readString(stdin);
    printf("Give me a string5:\n");
    str5 = readString(stdin);
    printf("Give me a string6:\n");
    str6 = readString(stdin);

    char *cond;
    cond = diffFun((char* str1,char* str2,char* str3,char* str4,char* str5,char* str6);
    printf("%ls",cond);

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `readString()`?? is that a user defined function??

Comment: What are the errors? Also show us the minimum code not all of it. What is the function call to diffFun meant to do what are the char* inn that line meant to do? Which tutorial are you working from?

Comment: you should not repeat the type of variables when calling a function. Also you have there double "("...
you might be confused by unintialized variables when the function has anonymous arguments and declare local variables inside the function...
what should it mean strcmp with one or five arguments?

Comment: Im new to programming so I am so lost. These are my errors: pract.c:5: error: parameter name omitted
pract.c:5: error: parameter name omitted
pract.c:5: error: parameter name omitted
pract.c:5: error: parameter name omitted
pract.c:5: error: parameter name omitted
pract.c:5: error: parameter name omitted
pract.c: In function ‘main’:
pract.c:32: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: pract.c:34: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
pract.c:36: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
pract.c:38: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
pract.c:40: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
pract.c:42: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
pract.c:45: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘str1’
pract.c:45: error: expected expression before ‘;’ token
pract.c:49: error: too few arguments to function ‘diffFun’
pract.c:49: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token

Comment: Where are variable name in function definition 'diffFun'?? Does strcmp take other than 2 arguments?? Where is 'readString' defined??

Comment: readString should be a built in function

Comment: And add the error message to the question (use the `edit` button)

Comment: I did. They are in the comments above. There are a lot

Comment: You probably should gather some basic knowledge of the C language.

Comment: I have tried that and it just pops up a whole new list of errors @user3121023

Comment: these are just some of them @user3121023  error: ‘s1’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
pract.c:5: error: previous definition of ‘s1’ was here
pract.c:8: error: ‘s2’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
pract.c:5: error: previous definition of ‘s2’ was here
pract.c:9: error: ‘s3’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
pract.c:5: error: previous definition of ‘s3’ was here
pract.c:10: error: ‘s4’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
pract.c:5: error: previous definition of ‘s4’ was here

Comment: diffFun returns a large string lexicographically in the string is the longest length of the string?

Comment: What **excatly** is `readString` ? There is no such builtin function in C. Show us that function, it is probably as messsed up as the rest of your program.

Comment: Try to start coding in increments, starting with a few lines, checking if it compiles and works, and then add more complexity in little steps always trying to compile every few lines (at least as you learn).

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand well, but I feel like the following...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* diffFun(int n, char *s[n]){
    int i, j;
    char *result = s[0];
    size_t result_len = strlen(result);

    for(i = 1; i < n; ++i){
        size_t len = strlen(s[i]);
        if(result_len < len){
            result = s[i];
            result_len = len;
        } else if(result_len == len && strcmp(result, s[i]) < 0){
            result = s[i];
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main(void){
    char *str[6];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<6; i++){
        printf("Give me a string%d:\n", i+1);
        str[i] = readString(stdin);
    }

    char *cond = diffFun(6, str);
    printf("%s",cond);

    return 0;
}
```